# What automated testing software is available for Android apps?

Tags: android, automation, software-testing

I've built an Android app that needs to be able to connect to a server that pushes notifications to it.
What I want to test is:
Setting up an internet connection

- Handling failure to set it up
- Handling a sudden drop of connection
- Setting up a link with the server
- Handling failure to set up that link
- Handling a sudden break of that link
- And comparing the notifications that have been sent to the notifications that have been received.

I have built the app using Delphi XE7.